# jboss spring applicationContext load on start in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, wildfly, applicationcontext

I am using wildfly 8.2.0. I want to load spring-config.xml on start
However, it`s unsuccessful. What am i doing wrong?

This is my web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

```
<display-name>BQP</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>src/main/resources/spring-config*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.bionic.rest.ApplicationConfiguration</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For spring MVC you can load configuration xml form web.xml like below
it will load while application startup

```
<!-- Spring MVC     -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Comment: I use org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher, won't it be a problem to use rg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet?