# Avoid creating ApplicationContext in each method

Tags: java, spring

I have my REST controller and method inside:

```
@GET
@Path("/tests/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getAvailableTestsNames(@PathParam("id") String id){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
    StudentService studentService = (StudentService)context.getBean("studentService");
    Set<TestDTO> testDTOs = studentService.getAvailableTestsNames(id);

    return Response.status(200).entity(testDTOs).build();

}
```

How cain i avoid creating ApplicationContext each time? I want to create it on start and use @Autowired annotation to inject my beans

I also asked about that here:
[jboss spring applicationContext load on start in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778368/jboss-spring-applicationcontext-load-on-start-in-web-xml/33778527#33778527)
However, the solution does not work for me. i still get an error

Comment: What error ? Show us.

Comment: Do you have **any** spring context? How is the controller loaded? Not using spring?

Comment: The best advice is to suggest reading some documentation and official tutorials instead of jumping head-first into coding.

Comment: @kryger you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate your rest controller with @RestController annotation and start injecting your services with @Autowired.

Comment: I did that and get NullPointer on service injected by @Autowired

Comment: That means is there an error with you configuration, can you put more source code?